# Trouble setting the WooCommerce store base page & store title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue with woocommerce where my shop page is taking the title of the first product and using it as the shops title... I figured that I could fix this by setting the base page of the shop, But I couldn't find the settings to do this in the WooCommerce settings. As you can see the shop base page is not set in the back end yet I see no option to set it. [image: WC page settings]

I also googled around and couldn't seem to find much on my issue. Here is the store I am referring to: http://museumofbuford.com/shop/

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a default theme? Have you set a shop page and it won't save? The shop base is found under Settings>Permalinks. Re-save your permalinks for good measure.

Comment: I managed to get the shop page set.. But my issue now is how can I change the title in the header/banner for the page.. http://museumofbuford.com/shop/ it is pulling the title of the first product as the name.... I literally just want it to say store.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My fault, I misunderstood. I think you need to create a page and then set it as the shop page in **WooCommerce>Settings>Products>Display**

[image: set shop base page]

From there the title of the shop page will be the title of this page and you can edit it like you'd edit any other WordPress page. Additionally, the slug will be the slug you designate for this page.

[image: change shop title]

The default theme still displays "Shop" as the page title by default. And I can see that your theme is displaying Shop too.

**HOWEVER**, the extra "page title" that your theme is providing is doing something whacky. It could be overriding `archive-product.php` or just providing a weird page title in the `header.php` or `header-shop.php`. I can't really say since I don't have that theme, but it does appear to be part of their [demo](http://preview.imithemes.com/vestige-wp/shop/).

So, this solves the problem of not having a shop base set, but it won't fix your theme. Your best bet is probably to contact the theme author and/or hire a developer to modify the theme.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help! I figured it must be something with the theme... I contacted them earlier today. Now to find out what the issue is.. You definitely helped me find that "hidden" menu for the Shop Base Page settings though! Thank you very much!